# ArrayList and more primitive types togheter in Java

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, primitive-types

I need to create a Java array list (precisly, a vector) that contain more than one primitive types.
For example, I would like to see in every vector's row about this:

```
row[0] --> "str1", 5, "str2", "str3", 3.5, 6, "str4"...etc...
row[1] --> "str5", 6, "str6", "str7", 5.3, 8, "str8"...etc...
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Well it sounds like you should create a new class to represent a single row... have you tried that? If so, what problem have you had? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: you need to create an object array, as you cant store them in standard array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a solution to your problem. I made a code that works for integer, string and float (the rest u can finish).

Main (with yours values)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Init
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Something>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Something> sublist1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Something> sublist2 = new ArrayList<>();
        //Fill array lists
        sublist1.add(new Something("str1", 0));
        sublist1.add(new Something(5, 1));
        sublist1.add(new Something("str2", 0));
        sublist1.add(new Something("str3", 0));
        sublist1.add(new Something(3.5f, 2));
        //etc
        sublist2.add(new Something("str5", 0));
        sublist2.add(new Something(6, 1));
        sublist2.add(new Something("str6", 0));
        sublist2.add(new Something("str7", 0));
        sublist2.add(new Something(5.3f, 2));
        //etc
        //Add the two list in the main
        mainList.add(sublist1);
        mainList.add(sublist2);
        //Iterator
        int i = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Something> sublist : mainList) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Results from list " + i);
            for (Something something : sublist) {
                switch (something.getType()) {
                    case 0: {
                        System.out.println("String value: " + (String) something.getValue());
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: {
                        System.out.println("Integer value: " + (Integer) something.getValue());
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        System.out.println("Float value: " + (Float) something.getValue());
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Class Something:

```
public static class Something {

        private Object value;
        private int type;

        /**
         * Constructor of Something class
         *
         * @param value
         * @param type type 0 String <br/>
         * type 1 Integer <br/>
         * type 2 float ....
         */
        public Something(Object value, int type) {
            this.value = value;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

    }
```

Output of the main:

```
Results from list 1
String value: str1
Integer value: 5
String value: str2
String value: str3
Float value: 3.5
Results from list 2
String value: str5
Integer value: 6
String value: str6
String value: str7
Float value: 5.3
```

Comment: Thanks!! I think that your solution is better for me! :) You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list of list..like below

```
    Vector<Vector<Object>> list = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    Vector<Object> row1 = new Vector<Object>();
    row1.add(5);
    row1.add("John");

    Vector<Object> row2 = new Vector<Object>();
    row1.add(1.1);
    row1.add("Aby");

    list.add(row1);
    list.add(row2);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Java generics cannot contain primitive types. You have to use corresponding object type. e.g. Integer or Float.

To put objects of many types into a container declare it to hold a supertype:

```
Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
v.add("String");
v.add(new Integer(5));
```

Mind that when you do `v.get(0)` you will receive an object of type `Object`. You have to know to what type you want to cast it back.

To check a runtime type of an object you can use `Object.getClass()`, or compare it with a known type using `instanceof` operator like this:

```
if(object instanceof String){
    // do something with a String
}else{
    // do something with a Number (Integer etc.)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no neat-and-easy way to store mixed-type data in a uniform manner in Java. So you better define List of Object to store row contents and prepare to write huge IF:

```
if (row[i] instanceof String) {
 ...
} else if (row[i] instanceof Integer) {
 ...
}
```

and so on. I did that when worked with protobuf, emulating mix-typed fields.

**And more:** Forget about primitives, if you are going to use *List*. Java generics are incompatible with primitive types, unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 1):

As you items in array represent some logical order you can try to create a representation of them in form a data structure like class.

```
class NameOfStructure {
  private String str1;
  private int    int1;
  private String str2;
}
```

An later put that structure into array.

```
NameOfStructure[] rows = new NameOfStructure[size];

NameOfStructure row = NameOfStructure[0];

String str1 = row.str1;
 int   int1 = row.int1;
```

An alternative option is to create array type of Object[], but then you must cast the type to expected after retrieving an item from array.

```
Object[] row = new Object[size];
...
String  str1 = (String)  row[0];
Integer int1 = (Integer) row[1];
```